# SwiftyJson append json object as key value

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have searched the site for a solution to this, but sadly have not been able to find one. I have an existing json object to which I am trying to append this onto using SwiftyJson:

```
"photo_id" : {
    "base_identifier" : {
        "DSL" : {
            "photo_id" : "56d5d88eb04b925b68d75fcb"
         }
      }
  }
```

I have tried a few of the solutions so similar questions I have found here but none of them seem to accomplish what I am attempting to do.

Thanks guys!

> Details:  Xcode 7.3 | Swift 2.2 | SwiftyJSON 2.3.1

Comment: `I have tried a few of the solutions` Which ones? What didn't work? Maybe we can explain what was the issue with what you tried.

Comment: Eric D I was actually able to fix it with the solution I posted below. Apologies for not adding detailed solutions I had already tried.

Comment: Hey, no problem - I was just trying to improve your question. :) It's nice that you found a solution and that you posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was able to figure it out after further reading of the [SwiftyJSON Documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization). I was simply initializing the object to append incorrectly. Simply initializing the correct way was able to achieve what I wanted:

```
let emptyJSON: JSON = JSON([:])
```

and then simply add the correctly initialized empty json object where I needed it. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I ended up finding the answer to this and posting it here. Im not sure if I'm allowed to accept my own answer as best answer? It did indeed solve the issue at hand.